# Restricting database access to specific Windows groups in SQL Server 2008

Tags: database, windows, sql-server-2008, permissions

I'm trying to restrict access to a database on my server to only allow users from a specific Windows group.

I have enabled Windows authentication for the server, but it seems as if I can only allow access to specific users, not specific groups...

Is there any way I can do this?

Most of the resources I've found contain `SQL Server 2005` specific instructions, and I have thus far been unable to translate them over to `2008`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

In the New user Dialog click the `Search button`.
Then click `Object Types`.
Select `Groups`, deselect `Users` and `Built-in Security Principals`
Click `Ok`.
Then click on `Find Now`

At this point you should see a list of groups available.
Pick the one you want and click `OK`.

Assign rights as necessary.

Comment: I was looking at the wrong dialog - instead of adding the group to the server first, I was trying to add the group to the database.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2005 and 2008 are essentially the same here.

```
USE master
CREATE LOGIN [domain\group] FROM WINDOWS
GRANT CONNECT SQL TO [domain\group]

USE MyDB
CREATE USER [domain\group] FROM LOGIN [domain\group]
GRANT CONNECT TO [domain\group]
```

This will allow everyone in the windows group to connect to your database. Is that what you want?

Or do you want to deny some folk access, which I thought at first...

Comment: gbn, your code results in this in SQL 2008 R2 Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GRANT'.